# Client-go - Getting the generated name before creating an object in Kubernetes using client-go

Tags: kubernetes, client-go

Let's suppose that I have such code to generate new pod

```
req := &api.Pod{
        TypeMeta: unversioned.TypeMeta{
            Kind:       "Pod",
            APIVersion: "v1",
        },
        ObjectMeta: api.ObjectMeta{
            GenerateName: "name-, // need to get that name, before creating an object
        },
        Spec: api.PodSpec{
            Containers: []api.Container{
                {
                    Name:  "nginx",
                    Image: "nginx",
                    Env:   []corev1.EnvVar{} // pass here the generated name,

                },
            },
        },
}
...
// Do some work on the generated name, before creating the resource in Kubernetes cluster
...
err := client.Create(context.Background(), req)
```

Is it possible to get that generated name before creating an object? Or is it possible to store that generated name in the env of the same object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generated name seem to be created in conjunction with the apiServer. See [Issue comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44501#issuecomment-294255660) and [Kubernetes API Concepts - Generated values](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#generated-values).

It is recommended to not depend on it. Typically, labels and selectors is more common in the Kubernetes ecosystem.

```
Env:   []corev1.EnvVar{} // pass here the generated name,
```

You can use the Downward API for this.
Example:

```
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about that, I'll definitely take a look. Once again, thanks!

Comment: How would you add the env from the Downward API here []corev1.EnvVar{}??